# Finding and replacing elements in Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to be able to search a Linked List for certain unique elements (username, password, email) and after finding these elements I need to go to the next node in the list and begin a series of statements allowing users to change profile information. For some reason my code just doesn't work and I have no idea how to fix it. Any help would be great!

**How GUI Looks**

[image: GUI]

**Link to Account Class:** http://pastebin.com/jnBrcnP1

So the User fills out the Required information and if they want to change profile information such as "Name" or "Gender" they change the information then set the ComboBox next to it to "Yes" then click the button "Save Settings".

**Here is what the Linked List looks like:**

```
tobi
tobi123
tobi@hotmail.com
tobi
Mixed Breed
Male
1-2
Virginia
Walking
peppy
peppy123
peppy@hotmail.com
peppy
Chihuahua
Male
5-6
Virginia
Eating
```

**Here is my button code:**

```
private void jButtonP1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    //New Linked List created from file
    LinkedList<Account> account = new LinkedList<Account>();

    try
    {
        read(account, "doggydates.txt");
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
        display(account);

    //user information
    String username = jTextFieldP3.getText();
    String password = jPasswordFieldP1.getText();
    String email = jTextFieldP4.getText();
    String name = jTextFieldP1.getText();
    String breed = (String) jComboBoxP4.getSelectedItem();
    String gender = (String) jComboBoxP3.getSelectedItem();
    String age = (String) jComboBoxP1.getSelectedItem();
    String state = (String) jComboBoxP2.getSelectedItem();
    String hobby = jTextFieldP2.getText();
    //change combo boxes
    String passchange = (String) jComboBoxP13.getSelectedItem();
    String emailchange = (String) jComboBoxP14.getSelectedItem();
    String namechange = (String) jComboBoxP6.getSelectedItem();
    String breedchange = (String) jComboBoxP7.getSelectedItem();
    String genderchange = (String) jComboBoxP8.getSelectedItem();
    String agechange = (String) jComboBoxP9.getSelectedItem();
    String statechange = (String) jComboBoxP10.getSelectedItem();
    String hobbychange = (String) jComboBoxP11.getSelectedItem();

    //cancel combo box
    String accountcancel = (String) jComboBoxP5.getSelectedItem();

    if(username.equals("") || password.equals("") || email.equals("")) // If password and username is empty > Do this >>>
    {
        jButtonP1.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldP3.setText("");
        jPasswordFieldP1.setText("");
        jTextFieldP4.setText("");
        jButtonP1.setEnabled(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    else
    {
        ListIterator<Account> itr = account.listIterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) 
        {
            Account item = itr.next();
            if(item.getUsername().equals(username) && item.getPassword().equals(password))
            {

                if(passchange.equals("Yes"))
                {    
                    for(Account acc : account){
                        if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)){
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.setDataAtCurrent(password);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(emailchange.equals("Yes"))
                {    
                    for(Account acc : account){
                        if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)){
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.setDataAtCurrent(email);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(namechange.equals("Yes"))
                {    
                    for(Account acc : account){
                        if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)){
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.setDataAtCurrent(name);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(breedchange.equals("Yes"))
                {    
                    for(Account acc : account){
                        if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)){
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.setDataAtCurrent(breed);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(genderchange.equals("Yes"))
                {    
                    for(Account acc : account){
                        if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)){
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.setDataAtCurrent(gender);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(agechange.equals("Yes"))
                {    
                    for(Account acc : account){
                        if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)){
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.setDataAtCurrent(age);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(statechange.equals("Yes"))
                {    
                    for(Account acc : account){
                        if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)){
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.setDataAtCurrent(state);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(hobbychange.equals("Yes"))
                {    
                    for(Account acc : account){
                        if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)){
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.setDataAtCurrent(hobby);
                        }
                    }
                }                    

                if(accountcancel.equals("Yes"))
                {    
                    for(Account acc : account){
                        if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)){
                            acc.deleteCurrentNode();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.deleteCurrentNode();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.deleteCurrentNode();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.deleteCurrentNode();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.deleteCurrentNode();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.deleteCurrentNode();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.deleteCurrentNode();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.deleteCurrentNode();
                            acc.goToNext();
                            acc.deleteCurrentNode();
                        }
                    }
                }  

            }
        }

        String file_name = "doggydates.txt";
        try {
                FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file_name);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

                ListIterator itr2 = account.listIterator();
                while (itr2.hasNext()) {
                    Account element = (Account) itr2.next();
                    out.write("" + element);
                    out.newLine();
                }
                out.close();
                System.out.println("File created successfully.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}
```

**Read Method:**

```
public static void read(LinkedList<Account> account, String inputFileName) throws java.io.IOException{
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));
    while(infile.ready())
    {        
    String username = readLine(infile);
    String password = readLine(infile);
    String email = readLine(infile);
    String name = readLine(infile);
    String breed = readLine(infile);
    String gender = readLine(infile);
    String age = readLine(infile);
    String state = readLine(infile);
    String hobby = readLine(infile);

    Account a = new Account(username, password, email, name, breed, gender, age, state, hobby);
    account.add(a);
    a.showList();
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Why are you searching twice for the same account? You already have the right object via the Iterator.

Comment: Your comment says "If password **AND** username is empty > Do this", but your code says "if password **OR** username **OR** email is empty..."

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it really doesn't seem like a list is the right structure here... Maybe a Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you do this:

First, `LinkedList<Account> account = new LinkedList<Account>();` this means that you're creating the list every time the user clicks *Save Settings* button.

Second, `ListIterator<Account> itr = account.listIterator();`, but account is an empty list! So you can't compare any single object with any of your people data.

Last, but not least, `read(account, "doggydates.txt");` I guess you're reading the file data and filling your list, after all the comparisons have been done.

Reorganize your code and try again.

UPDATE:
After reviewing all your code, I find some issues in your design:

1. The `Account` class is your entity. This class must have the data for your list. You can reuse this class like a Node of a LinkedList, specifying the pointer to other `Account` object reference, no need to use `ListNode` instance.
2. To implement a LinkedList, you're using the `Account` class. But this is inside a `LinkedList<Account>`, so you have a LinkedList of LinkedLists. I guess you don't want this behavior.

You could change your design to something more simple. I'll give you 2 samples for your design:

Form 1. Using your `Acount` class as a LinkedList node.

```
public class Account {

    private Account next;
    private Account previous;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private String gender;
    private String age;
    private String state;
    private String hobby;

    //constructor logic...

    //getters and setters...

    //toString method (for System.out.println)
}

public class AccountLinkedList {
    private Account head;
    private int size;
    public AccountLinkedList() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.head = null;
    }
    public boolean insert(Account account) {
        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = account;
        } else {
            Account current = head;
            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            //maintain the LinkedList order
            current.setNext(account);
            account.setPrevious(current);
        }
    }
    public Account findAccount(Account account) {
        Account current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.equals(account) {
                return current;
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return null;
    }
    //create the other methods to search, delete and traverse your list...
}

public class MyProgram {
    public void jButtonP1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Account account = new Account();
        //set the account data, I'll just stick to username and
        //password attributes
        String username = jTextFieldP3.getText();
        String password = jPasswordFieldP1.getText();
        account.setUsername(username);
        account.setPassword(password);
        //perform the update
        updateData();
    }
    public void updateData(Account account) {
        AccountLinkedList accountList = new AccountLinkedList;
        //loading data into our list
        loadDataFromFile(accountList, "myFile.txt");
        //perform the search operation
        Account accountAux = accountList.findAccount(account);
        //if the account is found, then update the accountAux data
        if (accountAux != null) {
            updateAccountData(accountAux, account);
        } else {
            accountList.insert(account);
        }
        //saving the modified data
        saveDataToFile(accountList, "myFile.txt");
    }
}
```

Form 2. Use the `Account` class like an entity and use the Java LinkedList implementation:

```
//check that now you don't have the next and previous attributes
public class Account {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private String gender;
    private String age;
    private String state;
    private String hobby;

    //constructor logic...

    //getters and setters...

    //toString method (for System.out.println)
}

public class MyProgram {
    public void jButtonP1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Account account = new Account();
        //set the account data, I'll just stick to username and
        //password attributes
        String username = jTextFieldP3.getText();
        String password = jPasswordFieldP1.getText();
        account.setUsername(username);
        account.setPassword(password);
        //perform the update
        updateData();
    }
    public void updateData(Account account) {
        LinkedList<Account> accountList = new LinkedList<Account>();
        //loading data into our list
        loadDataFromFile(accountList, "myFile.txt");
        //perform the search operation
        ListIterator<Account> li = accountList.listIterator();
        Account accountAux = null;
        while(li.hasNext()) {
            accountAux = li.next();
            //matching the account data outside with the current account
            //of the list iterator, this is just a sample, you can change
            //this logic
            if (accountAux.equals(account) {
                updateAccountData(accountAux, account);
                break;
            }
            accountAux = null;
        }
        //in case the account was not fount in the LinkedList, add it.
        if (accountAux == null)
            accountList.add(account);
        //saving the modified data
        saveDataToFile(accountList, "myFile.txt");
    }
}
```

IMO, I'll stick to Form 2 instead of Form1. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Okay so I moved the code for reading the file right after the list is made but I still get the error that im iterating with an empty list.

Comment: @GeorgeKingoftheZombiesSpeach have you checked that your `read(account, "doggydates.txt");` is actually working? have you made a test? Maybe the doggydates.txt is not the file with your data, or doggydates.txt is empty.

Comment: Yeah before it gives the error of trying to iterate empty list it displays the linked list properly. It reads the data properly from the file and saves it properly too.

Comment: @GeorgeKingoftheZombiesSpeach can you update your `jButtonP1ActionPerformed` method code?

Comment: done, all i did was move the file code under the creation of the linked list. still nothing

Comment: @GeorgeKingoftheZombiesSpeach i've updates my answer. Check to see if it helps you.

Comment: Sweet thanks for the help. I will most likely have to use form 1 because of the fact I have 5 different GUI classes that all have to have access to the linked list. By the way this is just for my peace of mind, this project has already been turned in. I just want to fix it and optimize it for future reference.

Comment: @GeorgeKingoftheZombiesSpeach any of the two ways will work for your project. Of course, if you want to learn about implementing your own LinkedList you should go with Form1.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to reconsider your design. I see that you are mixing the concept of the linked lsit of parameters in Account Class and the Linked List of Account instances.

An option that you may want:
You have a linked list of accounts, for your example the linked list should have two objects of Account.

```
LinkedList<Account> accounts = new LinkedList<Account>();
load(accounts, file);
```

which should have two objects {tobiaccount, peppyaccount} you need to write a load function here, that's another question.

Then, each account may have its own linked list for their parameters if that's really what you want.

Then you wil have a link list of link lists (accounts)

```
{
   {tobi, tobi123, tobi@hotmail.com, tobi, Mixed Breed, Male, 1-2, Virginia, Walking},
   {peppy, peppy123, peppy@hotmail.com, peppy, Chihuahua, Male, 5-6, Virginia, Eating}
}
```

If you want to go this way, you should consider simplifying your Account class and be sure the list inside it is populated correctly.

**HOWEVER**, this is still not a good design unless you are doing a weird homework about linked lists.

The optimal design would be using a single linked list, not a nested one; putting the Accounts on a linked list and accessing each parameter by the set/get methods you already have in the Account class.

Comment: Okay to be honest I know my account class is messed up I havent had time to fix it yet. Basically I have been finding advice from many different sources so im confused. I know that making a linked list using type Account means that its a linked list of objects. I think it would be better to do just a linked list of strings but I am just working with what I have

Comment: I just need to know how to fix my iterator so I am finding the values correctly. Right now my iterator isnt returning anything cause the list is empty. Ill optimize everything after I get it running.

Comment: Ok, let's stick with what we have here. Biggest problem is you have the "account" to iterate is empty while you are trying to iterate it. Are you going to populate it with calling read()? What is the read() function like?

Comment: And your linked list is going to be a list of strings, not accounts. Which makes your account class useless for what you want.

Comment: yeah it uses the read method to read the lines from the file and then makes a new account object, adds them into the account object and then adds them to the linked list.